# Delete downloaded robolectric jars

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

I am writing a Gradle task around Robolectric in Android Studio. How can I delete the jars that it downloads at runtime? I need a clean slate to test my task.
I tried running `clean` but that didn't cause the jar to be redownloaded on next run.

Is there a command I can run? Or where can I find the directory for downloaded jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a designated clean command, but I found a workaround:

1. Run test with debug flag `-d`; can be set either in `Preferences>Compiler>Command-line Options`, or run from terminal with `./gradlew :app:testDebugUnitTest -d --tests com.package.YourTestClass.testMethod > gradle_log.txt 2>&1`
2. In the logs, search for this: `Dependency cache location:`

The destination directory be specified on that line. Then you can just remove it `rm -r /var/folders/directoryname`